# SwiftUI PDFView do not update when documentURL changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, pdfkit, uiviewrepresentable

I try to make simple pdf viewer in swiftui. When I choose pdf using fileImporter for a first time it shows but when I do it for a secound time it do not change even if .navigationTitle changes. I should change when `@EnvironmentObject` changes. It is probably very simple but i cannot find any good good tutorial for this case.

This is my PDFView

```
//
//  CustomPDFView.swift
//  PDFToSpeach
//
//  Created by Dawid Paćkowski on 13/06/2023.
//

import SwiftUI
import PDFKit


struct CustomPDFView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var file: File

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                PDFKitView(documentURL: file.url)
                    .navigationTitle(file.name)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PDFKitView:UIViewRepresentable{
    var documentURL: URL?
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let pdfView: PDFView = PDFView()
        
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: self.documentURL!)
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical

        return pdfView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

i change `@EnvironmentObject` like this in `ContentView.swift`

```
.fileImporter(isPresented: $openFile, allowedContentTypes: [UTType.pdf]) { result in
            do {
                let fileURL = try result.get()
                file.url = fileURL
                file.name = fileURL.lastPathComponent
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your `PDFView` in `PDFKitView` when `updateUIView` method is called, which gets called by SwiftUI when it is updating views

Here's modified `PDFKitView`. Plus I added a couple of improvements like checking for nil to not crash

```swift
struct PDFKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var documentURL: URL?

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView: PDFView = PDFView()
        // check if url exists then set a new document
        if let documentURL {
            pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL)
        }
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: Context) {
        // take the updated document url and apply
        // check if url exists then set a new document
        if let documentURL {
            uiView.document = PDFDocument(url: documentURL)
        } else {
            uiView.document = nil // clear the document in case if url is nil
        }
    }
}
```

It basically takes the new document url, creates a new `PDFDocument` with it, and sets it to the pdfView(which can be accessed with `uiView` parameter in `updateUIView` (make sure to return the same type in `makeUIView`, in this situation it must return `PDFView`)), just like in `makeUIView`

Also make sure that modifying your `File` object triggers view update